# I have problem importing ITHit from 'webdav.client'

Tags: vue.js, webdav

I have an issue when trying to import the library. For some reason, it's not working. I have downloaded it using yarn

I'm working on a client-side project with `Vue3 + TS`.

I'm doing the following:

```js
import { ITHit } from 'webdav.client';
```

And the following error occurs, as shown in the image:
[console.log error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HL9El.png)

Comment: The error sort of suggest to me that there may be a bug in the library, but not a 100% certain.

Comment: I think so... And they don't answer my question